# Partial update of embedded document in mongoDB using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have the following model:

```
type UserModel struct {
    Id        string              `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time          `bson:"createdAt,omitempty"`
    BasicInfo *UserBasicInfoModel `bson:"basicInfo,omitempty"`
}

// *Embedded document*
type UserBasicInfoModel struct {
    FirstName    *string `bson:"firstName,omitempty"`
    LastName     *string `bson:"lastName,omitempty"`
}
```

I am using pointers, in order to be able to distinguish between a missing value (`nil`) and default value (eg *empty* strings, *false* values etc). I also use `omitempty` to be able to do partial updates.

When I **create** a user I get the following (correct) response back:

```
"id": "aba19b45-5e84-55e0-84f8-90fad41712f6",
"createdAt": "2018-05-26T15:08:56.764453386+03:00",
"basicInfo": {
    "firstName": "Initial first name",
    "lastName": "Initial last name"
}
```

When I try to **update** the document though I have an issue.
I send the changes as a new `UserModel`, to only change the `FirstName` field in the embedded document like this:

```
newFirstName := "New Value"
UserModel{
  BasicInfo: &UserBasicInfoModel{
    FirstName: &newFirstName,
  },
}
```

The code I use to do the **update** is the following:

```
UpdateId(id, bson.M{"$set": changes})
```

The response I get back is the following:

```
"id": "aba19b45-5e84-55e0-84f8-90fad41712f6",
"createdAt": "2018-05-26T12:08:56.764Z",
"basicInfo": {
    "firstName": "New Value",
    "lastName": null
}
```

The `createdAt` value **is not `null`** (as I expected) however the `lastName` value **is `null`** (which is not what I expected)

I would have expected to get back the following:

```
"id": "aba19b45-5e84-55e0-84f8-90fad41712f6",
"createdAt": "2018-05-26T12:08:56.764Z",
"basicInfo": {
    "firstName": "New Value",
    "lastName": "Initial last name"
}
```

*What can I do to achieve a partial update in a subdocument using mgo?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First let's quickly explain your `createdAt` field. This is the value you save: `2018-05-26T15:08:56.764453386+03:00`. Know that MongoDB stores dates with millisecond precision, and in UTC timezone. So this date when saved and retrieved from MongoDB becomes `2018-05-26T12:08:56.764Z`, this is the "same" time instant, just in UTC zone and precision truncated to milliseconds.

Now on to updating embedded documents:

The short and unfortunate answer is that we can't do this directly with the `mgo` library and Go models.

### Why?

When we use the `,omitempty` option, and we leave some pointer fields at their zero value (that is, being `nil`), it's like if we were using a value whose type didn't even have those fields.

So in your example, if you only change the `BasicInfo.FirstName` field, and you use this value to update, it is equivalent to using these structures:

```
type UserModel struct {
    Id        string              `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    BasicInfo *UserBasicInfoModel `bson:"basicInfo,omitempty"`
}

type UserBasicInfoModel struct {
    FirstName    *string `bson:"firstName,omitempty"`
}
```

So the effect of your issued `update` command will be the following:

```
db.users.update({_id: "aba19b45-5e84-55e0-84f8-90fad41712f6"},
    {$set:{
        "_id": "aba19b45-5e84-55e0-84f8-90fad41712f6",
        "basicInfo": {
            "firstName": "New Value"
        }
    }}
)
```

What does this mean? To set the `_id` to the same value (it won't change), and to set the `basicInfo` field to an embedded document which only has a single `firstName` property. **This will erase the `lastName` field of the embedded `basicInfo` document.** So when you unmarshal the document after the update into a value of your `UserModel` type, the `LastName` field will remain `nil` (because it is not present in MongoDB anymore).

What can we do?

### Flatten the embedded document

One trivial solution is to not use an embedded document, but add fields of `UserBasicInfoModel` to `UserModel`:

```
type UserModel struct {
    Id        string     `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `bson:"createdAt,omitempty"`
    FirstName *string    `bson:"firstName,omitempty"`
    LastName  *string    `bson:"lastName,omitempty"`
}
```

### Hybrid with `,inline` option

This solution keeps the separate Go struct, but in MongoDB it will not be an embedded document (`BasicInfo` will be flattened just like in the previous example):

```
type UserModel struct {
    Id        string             `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time         `bson:"createdAt,omitempty"`
    BasicInfo UserBasicInfoModel `bson:"basicInfo,omitempty,inline"`
}
```

Note that `BasicInfo` needs to be a non-pointer if `,inline` is used. This is not a problem, as we can leave it being an empty struct if its fields are not to be changed, since its fields are pointers, so leaving them `nil` will not change them.

### Doing "manual" update

If you do need to use embedded document, the `mgo` library allows you to update specific fields of embedded documents, but then you have to "manually" construct the update document, like in this example:

```
c.UpdateId(Id, bson.M{"$set": bson.M{
    "basicInfo.firstName": newFirstName,
}})
```

Yes, this isn't convenient at all. If you do need this many times with different types, you may create a utility function that uses reflection, iterates over the fields recursively, and assemble the update document from fields which are not `nil`. Then you could pass that dynamically generated update doc to `UpdateId()` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After some research (on Java mongo driver questions) I found out that they say the same. Maybe the inline option would suit me best, since it will keep the go struct more organized, and I will have the document flattened to perform partial updates. It's weird though that this cannot be done.

Comment: @TheoK Note that a utility function could be created which would provide this functionality to you. I'd estimate this could be done with like 50 lines of code, which isn't that much if you think of it. Maybe it would be worth to you to implement this.

Comment: Thanks, @icza. I ran into this same issue as well and wrote a small package for generating the update document just as you said: https://github.com/chidiwilliams/flatbson.